# jinja2: print template logic as it executes

Tags: python, debugging, jinja2

Is it possible to enable any kind of debug mode in Jinja2, so that it prints the template logic as it it renders? For instance, for a template

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
{{i*2}}
{% endfor %}
```

something like

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
{{i*2}}: 0
{{i*2}}: 2
{{i*2}}: 4
{{i*2}}: 6
{{i*2}}: 8
{% endfor %}
```

The exact output format doesn't matter. I just want to be able to see which parts of my template logic are taking up render time.